# Error in excel365 when I turn it on

Tags: excel

When I turn my excel 365 I get an error "Add method from AddIns class has failed" and OK button.
What is the reason behind that error, how I can fix that?
On the fille attached you have a screen of the error (It's in Polish)

[image]

Comment: The picture you have posted seems to indicate that there is a problem with you SmartView for Office Add-In (by Oracle). So, I'd recommend that you contact Oracle support or try uninstalling and then re-installing the plugin. Anyway, StackOverlfow is a site for questions around coding:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask Since your question is not related to that I don't think you'll find much help here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is against rules of this forum. Use Microsoft Office support instead!

As your error header clearly states, it is not excel error per se, it is Oracle Smart view for Office error. So I suggest disabling it or looking into logs for that

Comment: Pls +1 my answer, if it helped ;)